# Target specific tabs of a p:tabView in p:printer

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to print multiple tabs but want to exclude some.

I tried the following:

```
<p:printer target="tabs:tab0,tabs:tab2" />
```

and

```
<p:printer target="tabs:tab0" />
<p:printer target="tabs:tab2" />
```

Neither worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played somewhat around it and it works only for a specific tab if the tab is *visible*. You can thus definitely not specify multiple tabs. You might want to post an [issue report](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/) about that to PrimeFaces, although solving that would be relatively hard.

As of now, to get it to work for a specific tab, you'd need to toggle the desired tab  visible in the button's `onclick` handler before print action is performed. You can use the `select()` function of the `<p:tabView>` widget for this wherein you pass the zero-based tab index.

Here's a kickoff example.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:tabView id="tabs" widgetVar="tabs">
        <p:tab id="tab1" title="tab1">tab1</p:tab>
        <p:tab id="tab2" title="tab2">tab2</p:tab>
        <p:tab id="tab3" title="tab3">tab3</p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
    <p:commandButton type="button" icon="ui-icon-print" value="Print tab2" onclick="tabs.select(1)">
        <p:printer target="tabs:tab2" />
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Comment: that is what i figured.  issue will be submitted shortly.  nice breakdown.